# Signed vs Unsigned comparison in LC3/LC4 hardware system

Tags: c, unsigned, signed, lc3

I am creating a C program that simulates from beginning to end a fictional LC4 hardware system (a slightly different version from the well-known LC3 system. I am currently on the comparison instructions that are handled by the arithmetic logical mux. They are listed as follows:

```
CMP Rs Rt: NZP = signed-CC(Rs-Rt) 0010sss00----ttt
CMPU Rs Rt: NZP = unsigned-CC(Rs-Rt) 0010sss01----ttt
CMPI Rs IMM7: NZP = signed-CC(Rs-SEXT(IMM7)) 0010sss10IIIIIII
CMPIU Rs UIMM7: NZP = unsigned-CC(Rs-UIMM7)
```

I understand the difference between comparing values in two registers vs. comparing one value in a register and another value that's extracted from an LC4 instruction (CMP vs. CMPI for example). Can someone explain to me precisely what it means to do a signed versus unsigned comparison(CMP vs. CMPU or CMPI vs. CMPIU), under what circumstances would you do either, preferably with examples? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Pointers or (usually) indices are unsigned. When comparing two pointers, the values should not be interpreted as twos-complement values. Otherwise, once a pointer crossed the threshold of half the max value of a word, it would appear negative, and in a comparison would look less than a pointer before this  threshold.

Another example is an unsigned timer or counter. We wouldn't want a value above the threshold of half the max value of a word to appear smaller than a value before this  threshold.

Comment: Thank you, but my question is dealing more with data at its most primitive level namely, if I'm performing a signed comparison ___ vs ___ or an unsigned comparison ___ vs ___, what types of numbers would I be comparing?

Comment: @J_code, in a C program, you can cast signed integer values to `unsigned` to perform an unsigned comparison. Alternatively, you can store the values in `unsigned int` variables, then the cast will be unnecessary. Similarly, you can cast unsigned values to `int` as long as the value is less than `INT_MAX`, or you can store the values in `int` variables, then the cast will be unnecessary.